# How to call minimize() and focus() in a React component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify, electron

I have an Electron example application that minimizes and maximizes the application window, and I would like to do the same in a React application. But how do I get the reference to the main application window in my React component?

My main.js program contains:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const {BrowserWindow} = electron;
...
function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 500, height: 300, 
                              frame: false, resizable: false });
    global.mainWindow = mainWindow;
    ...
}
```

In the Electron example, my app/index.js file contains:

```
var remote = require('electron').remote;
...
remote.getGlobal("mainWindow").minimize();
```

In my React example, my app/app.js file contains:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppContainer from './containers/app.container'

var remote = require('electron').remote;
```

However when running watch I get this error message:

```
npm run-script watch

> mydemo@1.0.0 watch /home/myname/nodejs/mydemo
> watchify app/app.js -t babelify -o public/js/bundle.js --debug --verbose

Error: Cannot find module 'electron' from '/home/myname/nodejs/mydemo/app'
```

My questions:

- how do I reference the "remote" from inside a React component?
- is there another way of referencing the main application window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out myself. This code works in a React component:

```
var remote = window.require('electron').remote;
remote.getGlobal("mainWindow").minimize();
```